# CSS Rule not parsed

Tags: css

This is part of a css file:

```
.imgContainer>img.wide {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.imgContainer>img.tall {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
}

/* header and its elements*/
#header {
    background-color: #1020B8;
    color: #FFF;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

#logo {
    color: #FFF;
    float: left;
    margin: auto 0;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

The `#header` rule is not parsed, why? The `#logo` rule is parsed. I have tested this in Chromium and Firefox. If I put the `.imgContainer` rules to the end of the file everything works right. I uploaded the whole css file here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5911008.

Comment: Without seeing the HTML it's nearly impossible to say. Why can't the `.imgContainer` stuff stay at the bottom if it works that way?

Comment: I think we would probably need to see the entire CSS file to see if there was a formatting error somewhere that is causing this.

Comment: #header is fine.  do you have an element on your page with the id="header"?

Comment: The main problem is that the header div disappeared because of the missing height declaration. I'm just interested in what the mistake might be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting.

You have a rogue character in your CSS just above the `#header` rule:

```
    .imgContainer>img.tall{
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    width:auto;
    }​
/*   ^ -- There! */
```

See it? Just there after the closing brace.

Here's a jsfiddle that reproduces the issue (at least for me; IE9):

- Not working: http://jsfiddle.net/2gTBT/
- Working: http://jsfiddle.net/2gTBT/1/

I think the character's a U+200B - zero width space.

Interestingly the [CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) seems *not* to catch this issue. [The spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#tokenization) seems pretty clear on the matter of invalid whitespace though:

> The token S in the grammar above stands for white space. Only the characters "space" (U+0020), "tab" (U+0009), "line feed" (U+000A), "carriage return" (U+000D), and "form feed" (U+000C) can occur in white space. Other space-like characters, such as "em-space" (U+2003) and "ideographic space" (U+3000), are never part of white space.

Comment: +1 Damn pesky Zero Width Space: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm

Comment: Nice catch buddy. Very nice catch. +1

Comment: And really it took two backspaces to erase the closing brace! Wow!

Answer (score 0):

Does your `#header` element get affected by any other CSS rules? A good way to check is the following:

1. Open your site in Chrome
2. Press `CTL-SHIFT-I` to bring up the Developer's Tools
3. Go to the Elements tab
4. Click on your `#header` element in the DOM tree
5. Look at the Styles drop-down to the right, and see if your CSS rules are getting overridde

Comment: you can use firebug in firefox for the same info (if you prefer firefox).

Comment: I checked this in Chromium and the css rule does not show up. This is why I stated that the rule is not parsed.

Comment: Hmmm. Does adding `!important` have any effect? If not, it's likely an HTML error, or an error elsewhere in your stylesheet.

Comment: `!important` does not help either.